# Recompile and reload IEx without leaving IEx

Tags: elixir

How to recompile and reload IEx(kill all processes). What I am going to reach is the same behavior when I exit console and start it again but without leaving IEx.

I do in function

```
IEx.Helpers.recompile()
Process.exit self, :kill
```

But I got red message: (EXIT from #PID<0.607.0>) shell process exited with reason: killed
Which is very annoying.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you use a framework like sugar, you can use hot-code-reload (check code example here: http://sugar-framework.github.io/getting-started/#configure-your-router), pretty sure Phoenix supports it too; Then your processes simply fail and are restarted when new sources are detected.

Comment: I run numerous bots manually from console during tests. They are GenStages which talk to each other and other web services, I do not use Phoenix. I do code changes and want to start from testing scratch in some situations.

Comment: but if you recompile,  kill everything, and destroy all state, what is the benefit of not restarting iex?

Comment: Btw, the easy fix is to start your processes under a common supervisor, then use that supervisor to kill / restart processes

Comment: Thank you, dualed, I will consider common supervisor, may be it will be useful for  some of my cases where I do not need to shutdown all the processes. The value is convenience to do it in one short command, for example "re", no need to press twice Ctrl-C to exit and then run interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there is no function in IEx.Helpers module to restart all processes. However, you can use Application module functions to stop/start your mix application.

A suggested solution is:

```
Application.stop(:my_app_name)
recompile()
Application.start(:my_app_name)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not kill manually started processes which I run during tests.